# Memcpy into an array inside a malloced structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof, memcpy

This is my scenario.

```
struct X {
char A[10];
int foo;
};
struct X *x;
char B[10]; // some content in it.
x = malloc(sizeof(struct X));
```

To copy contents from `B` to `A`, why is the following syntax correct:

```
memcpy(x->A, B, sizeof(x->A));
```

Here `x->A` is treated as a pointer, so we don't need `&`. But then we should need `sizeof(*x->A)` right? But with `*` it is not working, while without `*` it's working fine.

Is it like `sizeof` operator does not treat `A` like a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is NOT a pointer, it's an array. So `sizeof(x->A)` is the correct syntax, it's the size of the whole array, i.e, `10`.

It's true that in many situations, an array name is converted to a pointer to the first element. But `sizeof(arrayname)` is NOT one of them.

Comment: is this behavior of sizeof consistent on different C implementations and platforms. I now know it works this way with gcc on a x86 linux machine. What about others?

Comment: @vivekzhere It's guaranteed by the C standard, so all implementations should follow this rule.

Comment: @vivekzhere But be careful when the array name is passed as function argument, it decays into a pointer in that case.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof(*x->A) gives you the size of a char(1 byte), while size0f(x->A) gives you the size of the entire array(10bytes).

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(*x->A)` is equivalent to `sizeof(x->A[0])`.

`sizeof(*x->A)` is 1 bye here. So memcpy will happen for only one byte.

This is `sizeof(x->A)` is the correct procedure.

Comment: The size of `x->A[0]` is the size of one `char`, which is (by definition) `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Though in many cases array name decay to a pointer (like the first argument to `memcpy()` in your example), there are a few that don't and `sizeof` operator argument is one of them.  Other examples are unary `&` operator argument, etc.  C++ has more scenarios (e.g. initializer for array reference).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to previous comments

`sizeof(x->A)` is correct `sizeof(*x->A)` is not correct because `->` has higher precedence than `*` so first the address of A is obtained(X->A) then `*` again deference's it to first byte (one char byte).

Not to forget sizeof operator doesn't consider `'\0'` character. if the the string `"Hello"` is pointed by A then it returns 5 ( array size is 6 including '\0'),
so while copying to `B` you have to add `'\0'` explicitly or you can increase the number bytes to be copied by one as shown below.

```
memcpy(x->A, B, sizeof(x->A) + 1);
```